# WSO2 API Manager with C# .Net Back-end Service: Content Type Null in Logs and 404 Error

Tags: c#, api, wso2

I am using WSO2 API Manager 2.6 and my back-end REST Service is implemented in C# with a POST method. When API is invoked from the client (using postman or any other client), I receive 404 Error. Same back-end service works fine if invoked direct but doesn't work with WSO2 API Manager in between.

I enabled wire logs and I see that in the carbon logs, It shows content type as null.

Anyone faced similar issue or anyone can help resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml with disable chunking flag and add this sequence into the app in the api manager (IN flow).

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="disableChunkingSeq">
   <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
</sequence>
```

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Disable+Message+Chunking

Comment: Dear Fran,
Thanks for responding. I tried this sequence but still same error in the logs:
 DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"